# Simplyifying a Boolean Expression that has three variables in it

Tags: boolean-algebra

The following problem can be found at the following URL:
[Some problems related to digital logic](http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/s2007/PSETS/pset1.pdf)

It is problem number 26 on the webpage.
Problem:

Simplify the following expression using Boolean Algebra:
$$ (X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= ( 0 + Z \overline X + XY + ZY )(Z + Y) \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= ( Z \overline X + XY + ZY )(Z + Y) \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &=
    Z( Z \overline X + XY + ZY ) + Y( Z \overline X + XY + ZY ) \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &=
    Z \overline X + XYZ + ZY + Y( Z \overline X + XY + ZY ) \\
%
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X + XYZ + ZY + YZ \overline X + XY + ZY \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X + XYZ + ZY + XY + ZY \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X + ZY + XY \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X + YZ + XY \\
\end{align*}
However, the author of the problem has the following answer:
$$ XY + \overline X Z $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In not drawing a Karnaugh map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue from your last line
$$ (X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) = Z \overline X + YZ + XY $$
and notice that
$$ \begin{align}
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X (Y + \overline Y) + Z(X + \overline X)Y + (Z + \overline Z)XY \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X (\color{blue} Y + \overline Y) + Z(\color{red}X + \color{blue} {\overline X})Y + (\color{red} Z + \overline Z)XY \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X (\color{blue} Y + \overline Y) + (\color{red} Z + \overline Z)XY \\
(X + Z)(\overline X + Y)(Z + Y) &= Z \overline X + XY. \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I do not understand how you dropped the term $Z(X+\overline X)Y$ in coming up with the line 2nd from the bottom. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: For any boolean value \$A\$ we have that \$(A + \overline A)=1\$. We also have that, for any Boolean value \$B = B \cdot 1 = B(A + \overline A)\$. So I used the expression you have on the last line of your answer and just added a bunch of multiplicative/AND 1's $$ Z \overline X 1+ Y1Z + 1XY  $$ and then expanded those 1's with either \$X,Y\$ or \$Z\$

Comment: That I understood. I meant the line below that.

Comment: if you look at \$Z(X+\overline X)Y\$ half of it, \$ZXY\$, is implemented by the last term of the expression and the other half, \$Z\overline XY\$, is implemented by the first term. So I only "dropped" it because for any boolean value \$A\$ we have that \$A+A = A\$

Answer (score 0):

You followed a good process. But perhaps the easiest way to ***see*** what you missed is to notice this:

$$\begin{align*}
F &= Z\overline{X}+YZ+XY\\
&=Z\overline{X}+XY+YZ\\
&= \underbrace{\left(Z\overline{X}+XY\right)}+ \,YZ
\end{align*}$$

The gathered up part (the left term of the last equation above) is just a mux:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAZR7B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you feed in \$Z=1\$ and \$Y=1\$ then the mux output has to be **1**. If you **or** into your equation \$+Y Z\$, this contributes nothing when that term is true because the only way that term is true is if \$Z=1\$ and \$Y=1\$. But the mux already yields that term, in that case. So the right term of the last equation above makes no contribution.